# selenium web driver basic programs using java

Tags: java, selenium

I am a java programmer and I am new to use selenium libraries and I want to familiar with this. I have searched good amount of pages in Google but unable to find a correct place to learn basic selenium programming. Kindly suggest me a nice link to go through basic programs for a beginner in selenium.

My expectations would be opening and performing some operations like click a button, drag down a scroll bar, drop down a list etc,.

Comment: Record yourself clicking around in selenium, then in selenium to a convert to java code, this will give you a template to work from.  There's loads of examples on the net of this.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium official docs, all in one.

http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/

also, [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/selenium-users) & stackoverflow better way.

Comment: as per david99world, record from Selenium ide & export to the java language good for beginner level.

Answer (score 0):

```
    package nandu;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    public class Webpack {

    WebDriver d;

    @Test
    public void testAjax() throws Exception
    {
        d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3,TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        d.manage().window().maximize();

        d.get("http://www.veethi.com/places/india_banks-ifsc-micr-codes.html");


        Select bank=new Select(d.findElement(By.id("selBank")));
        bank.selectByIndex(4);
        Select state=new Select(d.findElement(By.id("selState")));
        state.selectByVisibleText("Andhra Pradesh");
        Select city=new Select(d.findElement(By.id("selCity")));
        city.selectByVisibleText("Hyderabad");
        Select branch=new Select(d.findElement(By.id("selBranch")));
        branch.selectByVisibleText("Banjara Hills");


        Thread.sleep(5000);


  }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void initilaization() throws Exception
    {
        d=new FirefoxDriver();


    }
    @AfterMethod
    public void teardown()
    {
        d.quit();
    }

}
```